# How to override the print preferences with CSS for various browsers?

Tags: css, web, printing, cross-browser, media-queries

I have the following CSS:

```
   @@media only print {
            @@page {
                size: A4 landscape !important;
                margin-top: 0mm !important;
                margin-bottom: 0mm !important;
            }
                #tblPrint tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
                    background-color: #ededed !important;
                }
            * {
                -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important;
            }
}
```

The problem is as follows:

1. The @@page properties don’t take effect on all browsers, and the default browser’s print preferences take effect, that is (Chrome: A4/Landscape), (Edge: A4/Portrait), (IE: A4/Portrait), even when I flip the size property to size: A3 portrait !important; the same default browser’s print preferences keeps taking effect.
2. As I use the “-webkit-print-color-adjust”, then the background-color property takes effect on Chrome even when I turn off “background graphics” feature from browser’s print preferences, however, it doesn’t take effect on IE unless I turn on the “Print Background Color and Images” feature from browser’s print preferences, as for the edge browser am not being able to make background-color CSS property take effect.

The solution I need is to force the properties specified by my CSS to override the Browsers’ Print preferences without having the user to need to specify the paper size, orientation and to check the “Background Graphics / Print Background Color and Images” from the browser Print Preferences for ALL Browsers, please help!!

Comment: You should add only one @

Comment: I tried that, but it only distorted the CSS, and when running the page the following error occured: The name 'page' does not exist in the current context

Comment: try this.. bottom of yours all style  @media print
{
}

Comment: also tried that, but nothing changed still @@page and background-color don't take effect

Comment: inside media you should remove @@.. just class or id

Comment: also tried replacing the @@page with 'body', but also didn't take effect on print preferences

Answer (score 0):

add bottom of stylesheet

**css**

```
@media print { 
    body{ background-color:#000;}
}
```

Comment: An explanation of why this works would add to the quality of this answer.

Comment: This is syntax of print view.. so you should use always like above code.. or you can you can use separate stylesheet to using media print

Comment: You should put some of that into the answer itself.  The comment above came from the review queue where this answer was slated for deletion.

Comment: pls share your css code.. i will add print view for example